# How to use blobs > 1GB in zodb relstorage with sqlite backend?

Tags: python, sqlite, blob, zodb, relstorage

I am trying to save a blob > 1GB via [relstorage](https://relstorage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in a sqlite backend. The following minimum working example

- removes any previously created databases along with the blob directory,
- create a new database and
- saves a blob with 1GB to the database.

Minimum Working Example:

```
import os
import shutil
from ZODB import blob, config

connectionString = """
%import relstorage
<zodb main>
<relstorage>
    blob-dir blob
    keep-history false
    cache-local-mb 0
    <sqlite3>
        data-dir .
    </sqlite3>
</relstorage>
</zodb>
"""

# cleaning up
for x in os.listdir():
    if "sqlite" in x:
        os.remove(x)

shutil.rmtree("blob", True)

# creating database
db = config.databaseFromString(connectionString)

with db.transaction() as conn:
    conn.root.blob = blob.Blob()
    with conn.root.blob.open("w") as f:
        f.write(b"\0" * 1024 ** 3)
```

During the commit (at the `__exit__` method of the db.transaction with-block) of the newly created object an error occurs with the following final exception:

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.

Saving a blob with size `1024 ** 2` does not raise the exception.

How is it possible to save a blob in a sqlite backend using relstorage without the usage of a shared blob directory?

Comment: the error is regrading data type not the size of the object. and ll you comment the line causing errror in your code ?

Comment: @Harkal I clarified the exact point where the exception occurs in the question. If a wrong type is being used, why is it working for smaller blobs (like ``1024 ** 2``)?

Comment: I suspect you're hitting the storage limit in sqlite.  See https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html.  If it works up to 10e9 bytes, that's your problem.  If so you could try a custom build with a larger limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my research, you can't store arbitrary sized blobs in this setup.  You are hitting the sqlite blob size limit (https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Your only options at this stage appear to be:

1. Don't store the blob in sqlite, e.g. by using a shared blob directory.
2. Increase the blob limit, using a custom build of sqlite (as covered in the above link).
3. Decrease the size of what you store - e.g. by compressing your blobs, or chunking your data into smaller blobs.
4. Move to a different storage backend.

Personally, I would be inclined to use the shared blob directory if I was using sqlite, but you have discounted that option, so I think your choices are limited.

Comment: What about spliting the large blob into multiple small blobs?

Comment: Fair point.  That's another way to reduce the size of what you put into each record.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the sqlite limits. I agree with you about your suggested options. I think in my context I'll go for splitting the blobs.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to save a blob > 1GB via relstorage in a sqlite backend.

A related answer is [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/332071/40065) one.

My suggestion would be to handle differently large blobs (e.g. bigger than 8 to 32MBytes in 2020) and small ones.

Large content would be saved as files, and your `sqlite` database would know (and store) the file path (e.g. some generated file path such as `/var/tmp/bigblob1234` on Linux. See [hier(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)...).

Small content would be saved as SQLITE blobs.

Of course both your [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) and the Python code using it should be improved. Be aware of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: But storing blobs as files is what shared blob storage does (https://relstorage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/relstorage-options.html)... and the OP disallowed that.